# Download, save and show images with sencha touch and phonegap

Tags: image, plugins, download, cordova, sencha-touch

I' have to download some images from a server folder and save in my `sencha` application to show them offline. I've found a `phonegap` [plugin](http://www.clearlyinnovative.com/blog/post/1097750723/phonegap-plugin-for-downloading-url#.UfDqjGR4eQo) that download and save files in document folder of the app. Once I saved the images how can I show them in my sencha app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably have a store with the images mapping their paths and use those with the phonegap File Api.

Answer (score 0):

For opening the file in device,you can use

```
window.plugins.fileOpener.open("file:///path_to file.jpg")
```

For more details refer to https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2